# Is there any way to use the return value as an argument to the same function during the previous recursion in merge sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion, data-structures, mergesort

I am coding the Merge sort algorithm but somehow got stuck with a problem. The problem is that I need to use the return value of the merge function as an argument as an previous recursive call of the same merge function. Sorry for not being clear.

Here is my code:

```py
a = [10,5,2,20,-50,30]

def mergeSort(arr):
   l = 0
   h = len(arr)-1
   if h > l:
      mid = (l+h) // 2
      left = arr[l:mid+1]
      right = arr[mid+1:]
      mergeSort(left)
      mergeSort(right)
      merge(left, right)

def merge(l, r):
   subarr = []
   lc = 0
   rc = 0
   loop = True
   while loop:
      if lc > len(l)-1 and rc <= len(r)-1:
         for i in range(rc, len(r)):
            subarr.append(r[i])
            loop = False
      elif lc <= len(l)-1 and rc > len(r)-1:
         for i in range(lc, len(l)):
            subarr.append(l[i])
            loop = False
      elif l[lc] < r[rc]:
         subarr.append(l[lc])
         lc += 1
         loop = True
      elif r[rc] < l[lc]:
         subarr.append(r[rc])
         rc += 1
         loop = True
      elif l[lc] == r[rc]:
         subarr.append(l[lc])
         subarr.append(r[rc])
         lc += 1
         rc += 1
         loop = True    

mergeSort(a)
```

Any help will be appreciated thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you tried use the `return` keyword?

Comment: Your Python code is misindented. It is confusing and error prone to not use the same amount of white space for each level of indentation. Also use more horizontal whitespace, especially around binary operators and after `,`. You code is hard to read for both you and other programmers.

Comment: @ggorlen yup I tried using the return keyword

Comment: @chqrlie yeah you are right sorry

Comment: I don't see any `return`s in the code here.

Comment: I tried using return but still it doesn't work @ggorlen

Comment: Can you show the code that does use it? I recommend following some pseudocode for the algorithm, or even looking at python implementation if you don't mind knowing the answer.

Comment: @Gagan: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to actually `return` the result.  Right now you return nothing so get `None` back.

Secondly, just assign to the same variable.  `left = mergeSort(left)` and so on.

**UPDATE:**

Here is a debugged version.

```
a=[10,5,2,20,-50,30]

def mergeSort(arr):
    l=0
    h=len(arr)-1
    if h>l:
        mid=(l+h)//2
        left=arr[l:mid+1]
        right=arr[mid+1:]
        # Capture the merge into variables here.
        left=mergeSort(left)
        right=mergeSort(right)
        # Need a return of the merge.
        return merge(left,right)
    # Need to return arr if arr has 0 or 1 elements.
    else:
        return arr


def merge(l,r):
    subarr=[]
    lc=0
    rc=0
    loop=True
    while loop:
       if lc>len(l)-1 and rc<=len(r)-1:
          for i in range(rc,len(r)):
            subarr.append(r[i])
            loop=False
       elif lc<=len(l)-1 and rc>len(r)-1:
          for i in range(lc,len(l)):
            subarr.append(l[i])
            loop=False
       elif l[lc]<r[rc]:
          subarr.append(l[lc])
          lc+=1
          loop=True
       elif r[rc]<l[lc]:
          subarr.append(r[rc])
          rc+=1
          loop=True
       elif l[lc]==r[rc]:
          subarr.append(l[lc])
          subarr.append(r[rc])
          lc+=1
          rc+=1
          loop=True
    # Need to return the results of merge.
    return subarr

# Need to actually try calling the function to see the result.
print(mergeSort(a))
```

I also indented more sanely.  Trust me, it matters.

Comment: Yeah I assigned the var to my mergeSort func plus I added the return keyword but it returns none

Comment: @Gagan Did you also add `return` to your `merge` function?

Comment: Yes I added the return keyword

Comment: @Gagan That is because if you pass `mergeSort` an array with 0 or 1 elements, it returns nothing.  I will update my answer with working code and indicate the changes.

Comment: @Gagan And please note that the number of things that needed fixing is not unusual.  You just need to learn the rules and then learn to be that careful.

Comment: Yup that was my fault I overlooked on that part and now it's completely working thanks to you @btilly

Comment: I appreciate your help brother @btilly

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in our code:

- you do not return the sorted slice from `mergeSort` nor `merge`. Your implementation does not sort the array in place, so you must return `subarr` in `merge` and the return value of `merge` in `mergeSort` or `arr` if the length is less than 2.
- your code is too complicated: there are many adjustments such as `mid+1`, `len(l)-1`, etc. It is highly recommended to use index values running from `0` to `len(arr)` excluded. This way you do not have to add error prone +1/-1 adjustments.
- the `merge` function should proceed in 3 phases: merge the left and right arrays as long as both index values are less than the array lengths, then append remaining elements from the left array, finally append remaining elements from the right array.
- there is no need to make 3 different tests to determine from which of the left and right array to take the next element, a single test is sufficient.
- also use a consistent amount of white space to indent the blocks, 3 or 4 spaces are preferable, tabs are error prone as they expand to different amount of white space on different devices, mixing tabs and spaces, as you did is definitely a problem.

Here is a modified version:

```py
def mergeSort(arr):
   # no need to use l and h, use len(arr) directly
   if len(arr) > 1:
      # locate the middle point
      mid = len(arr) // 2
      # left has the elements before mid
      left = arr[:mid]
      # right has the elements from mid to the end
      right = arr[mid:]
      # sort the slices
      left = mergeSort(left)
      right = mergeSort(right)
      # merge the slices into a new array and return it
      return merge(left, right)
   else:
      # return the original array (should actually return a copy)
      return arr

def merge(l, r):
   subarr = []
   lc = 0
   rc = 0
   # phase1: merge the arrays
   while lc < len(l) and rc < len(r):
      if l[lc] <= r[rc]:
         subarr.append(l[lc])
         lc += 1
      else:
         subarr.append(r[rc])
         rc += 1

   # phase2: copy remaining elements from l
   while lc < len(l):
      subarr.append(l[lc])
      lc += 1

   # phase3: copy remaining elements from r
   while rc < len(r):
      subarr.append(r[rc])
      rc += 1

   # return the merged array
   return subarr

a = [10, 5, 2, 20, -50, 30]
print(mergeSort(a))
```

Comment: thank you for modifying my code,I knew that I am making it complicated but didn't know the problem and you help me realized my problem thank you